Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:netezza.nzpy
I have some worries with using nzalchemy together with SQLAlchemy. I tried using version 1.4.52 and the latest 2.0 version, but the failure remains always the same.
Whenever I try to connect to some Netezza database I always get the error message sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:netezza.nzpy. The connection URI is fine, I checked it several times:
create_engine('netezza+nzpy://user:password@host:5480/database')

(Of course the values are just fake for this posting ...)
For my own curiosity I used create_engine('netezza+pyodbc:///') without any parameters, but there I get at least this error:
ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So, it seems that nzalchemy might work with ODBC but not when using nzpy, but can't explain the reason to myself.
List of installed modules:
nzalchemy         11.0.0
SQLAlchemy        1.4.52
pyodbc            5.1.0
nzpy              1.15

Any hints for me?
Btw, running nzalchemy with ODBC is not an option due to missing access rights on configuring ODBC on the target machine.

https://github.com/IBM/nzalchemy/issues/8#issuecomment-1486656847

Well, the problem is ODBC - can't install unixodbc on that machine, unfortunately.

You can use the following versions of the modules:
SQLAlchemy==1.3.24 
nzalchemy==11.0.2

The above configurations should work.
